# How do I get map coordinates in Far Cry 4

Tags: far-cry-4

Many of the guides have coordinates available for the locations on the map.

How do I enable those numbers or where can I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates are displayed in the bottom right hand corner of the map screen. See screen shot below:

[image: Far Cry 4 Map with co-ordinates highlighted, originally from Kotaku]

If you are looking to go to a specific set of coordinates you can open the map and find the coordinates by moving the cursor to the location then set a waypoint to get directions.

Comment: the coordinates only change when I drag the map (setting waypoint or making selection does not change X, Y)  So where does the (X, Y) points to, center of screen?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates are the centre of the screen, where the cursor is located on the map. If you set a way point it is at the coordinates displayed when you set it, if you move the map the coordinates displayed will change but the waypoint will still be in the original location.